# Combobox Datasource not creating items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox, datasource, bindinglist

After much searching I have still not found a solution to this.

I have created a list in *VS 2010* and bound it to a `ComboBox`. The `DataSource` property shows the entire list but the combobox on the form is empty, as is the items property of the box.

```
    private List<string> classes = new List<string>();
    private BindingList<string> bindingClasses;

        classes.Add("Spinning");
        classes.Add("Step");
        classes.Add("Pilates");
        classes.Add("Kickboxing");
        classes.Add("Body Sculpting");

        bindingClasses = new BindingList<string>(classes);
        classesComboBox.DataSource = bindingClasses;
```

I have also tried adding

`classesComboBox.DisplayMember = "Spinning";`

and without the bindingList between to no avail.

Why is this not working?

Comment: You don't specify if we are talking about web or desktop..

Comment: Combobox-es are not available in asp.net. The code works fine, make sure you place the code in `Form_Load` or something relevant. Also, if you change the content of your `BindingList` the dropdown will change as well.

Comment: Your example is working perfectly placing it into Form_Load. You should provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the BindingList, just set the DataSource to the List<String> itself.

```
List<string> classes = new List<string>();
classes.Add("Spinning");
classes.Add("Step");
classes.Add("Pilates");
classes.Add("Kickboxing");
classes.Add("Body Sculpting");

classesComboBox.DataSource = classes;
classesComboBox.SelectedItem = "Spinning";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
classesComboBox.DataBind();
```

You need to specify when it should grab the data.